# PostgreSQL mass insert into a table?

Tags: postgresql

I need to mass insert all the values from `col_a` into another table. I can do it one at a time like this:

```
INSERT INTO table_2 (col_a_id)
SELECT 'col_a_id'
FROM table_1
WHERE col_a = 'x';
```

But is there a way I can just insert all the columns?

*EDIT*

Lets say I have this table:

```
Col_a    |    Col_b    |
------------------------
1        |      a      |
2        |      b      |
3        |      c      |
```

Instead of checking what is in `col_a` can I just insert each instance of `col_a` into a table? so I'll have `1, 2 & 3` in `table_2`?

Comment: Just string them together.  SQL allows you do any combination of columns you wish, comma separated.

Comment: I figured you could, I just need the syntax for the query.

Comment: So what is the problem? Just include all your columns separated by comma .... btw `'col_a_id'`  is a string value or a field column name?

Comment: I think reading the postgresql manual might be of use in this case, https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-insert.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO table_2 (col1, col2, col3, .... , coln)
SELECT col1, col2, col3, .... , coln
FROM table_1
WHERE col_a = 'x';
```

**Note:** String are separated by single quote

```
SELECT 'this is a string'
```

Fieldname use double quote:

```
SELECT "myFieldName", "col1"
```

**EDIT:**

If you want check all columns for `'x'`

```
WHERE 'x' IN (col1, col2, col3, .... , coln)
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Now, instead of using a `WHERE col_a = 'x'` is there a way to get every `col_a`?

Comment: I added an example to the question. I hope it clears my question up!

Comment: well isnt clear, but if you want insert every value just remove the `WHERE` clausule